# Как задать родителя для произвольного типа записи в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как задать родителя для произвольного типа записи в Wordpress?

У меня есть страница с вакансиями по адресу

```
http://localhost/wordpress/вакансии/
```

Также есть произвольный тип записи

```
// Регистрируем тип произвольных записей
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
register_post_type('post-type-3', array(
            'label'  => null,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'               => 'Вакансии', // основное название для типа записи
                'singular_name'      => 'Career', // название для одной записи этого типа
                'add_new'            => 'Добавить вакансию', // для добавления новой записи
                'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление вакансии', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
                'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование вакансии', // для редактирования типа записи
                'new_item'           => 'Новое ____', // текст новой записи
                'view_item'          => 'Смотреть вакансию', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
                'search_items'       => 'Искать позицию', // для поиска по этим типам записи
                'not_found'          => 'Вакансия не найдена', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Вакансия не найдена в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
                'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
                'menu_name'          => 'Вакансии', // название меню
            ),
            'description'         => '',
            'public'              => true,
            // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
            // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
            'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
            // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
            'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
            'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
            'menu_position'       => null,
            'menu_icon'           => null,
            //'capability_type'   => 'post',
            //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
            //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
            // 'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => ['title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','custom-fields','page-attributes','post-formats'], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
            // 'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive'         => false,
            'rewrite'             => true,
            'query_var'           => true,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-category', // иконка в меню
        ) );
```

Сейчас если я перехожу на эту запись у меня в URL такая ссылка

```
http://localhost/wordpress/post-type-3/новая-вакансия-3/
```

А мне нужно чтоб ссылка была такая

```
http://localhost/wordpress/вакансии/новая-вакансия-3/
```

Сейчас просто даже пункт меню "Вакансии" не выделяется активным

Подскажите как сделать то что я хочу?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать как-то так:
Изменить

```
'rewrite' => true,
```

на

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8')
```

Или использовать плагины типа
https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/
и тп

Но вообще использовать в урлах "кириллицу" и пр [нестандарт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL)  я бы не рекомендовал.

А если не нужна кириллица, то лучше сразу бы и именовать как надо в `register_post_type`.
Например:

```
register_post_type('vacavsii', array(
```

Comment: Это я для примера кириллицу написал, чтоб понятнее было, а вообще на продакшене будет транслитерация.
Плагин не вариант вообще, не люблю использовать плагины.
Если можно подробнее о способе, без плагина.

Comment: @СергейГончарь, плагинофообия лечится изучением матчасти. и если надо еще "подробнее", то однозначно юзай плагины. Но я изменил ответ.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, но возможно кто то еще сталкивался с такой ситуацией, я объясню, я не хочу связываться с плагинами потому-как хочу чтоб это было именно написано в теме.

Comment: 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8')
Попробовал, урл пишет правильный, но при переходе на этот пост вылетает страница 404

Comment: @СергейГончарь пересохраните настройки постоянных ссылок в админке

Comment: @СергейГончарь в теме таких вещей не должно быть в принципе!! Либо в своём плагине либо использовать готовые. И да после манипуляций с ЧПУ надо зайти в настройки пермалинков. Можно не пересохранять, но пересохранение лишним не будет.

Comment: Ну 404 перестал выдавать, но всеравно при переходе в этот пост открывается страница новостей

Comment: Плюс есть еще такой момент, впринципе 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8') подходит но проблема в том что не попадает ссылка в хлебные крошки, то-есть теряется цепь вообще